# Vercel API end point for search sends back only results equal to the query term but not results that includes that term

Tags: javascript, react-hooks, endpoint, vercel

I have written a component with react hooks, following a tutorial, that fetches result based on one field of an object that has the following structure. `{ id: 1, text: "Run 10 km", complete: false }`

The user is supposed to search by the text of a todo task. I am using axios and I send the request to vercel.com like this:

```
    const getToDosBasedOnQueryTerm = async (query) => {

    try {
        const response = await axios(`https://todos-api-nuquyjkqpx.now.sh/todos?text=${query}`);

        console.log('**************************')
        console.log(query);
        console.log(response.data);
        console.log('**************************')
        return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};
```

Here are all the todos: https://todos-api-nuquyjkqpx.now.sh/todos

There is a problem with this approach. It returns the results that has the exact text as in the query. So, if I search for Do, it returns 'Do' but ignores 'Do More' and 'Do Nothing'.

Is it possible to search for all the records (todos) that contain the word searched by the user?

Please help!
Thanks